# What does the phrase "Soh Ne De Wa" mean?

Tags: phrases

I hear of it sometimes on YouTube but don't know what it means. Google didn't give any answer.  What does this phrase mean please?

(a comment asked for a link, so here it is: https://youtu.be/dSR7ObNCwrQ?t=31  (at 00:31))

Comment: A link to a youtube example would be helpful. I can't tell what the phrase is from your guess at spelling it.

Comment: thanks, it is added to the question

Comment: You sure it wasn't それでは (sore dewa)?

Comment: so I guess it is それでは... it means "then" or "if so, then", or "if that's the case, then"...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She says それでは [soredewa] and it means “then”. In this context, それ [sore] (“that”) doesn’t refer to anything in particular.

I can see why you heard it as それねは [sorenewa]. She speaks with a nasal voice throughout.

Comment: I thought she said "sonedewa"... but I guess the sound of "ne" and "re" is quite close... maybe "le", "ne", and "re" are similar sounding

Comment: @StefanieGauss: OK. I knew you heard ね somewhere but I put it in the wrong place. Yes, the Japanese /r/ is produced with the tip of the tongue touching the same area of the mouth (the alveolar ridge) as /n/ (and /d/, too). It does sound like /n/ if nasalized.